# ¿Cómo mostrar una alerta en React solo cuando se completen los campos de un formulario?

Tags: reactjs, formularios, submit

Estoy armando un formulario en **React** donde tengo 3 *campos* que son requeridos y necesito que al apretar el botón de **enviar** aparezca una alerta.

El problema es que aunque los campos no estén llenos si apreto el botón de **enviar** igual salta la alerta **enviado**. Necesito que si los campos estén vacios, no muestre la alerta de *enviado* al momento de dar clic al botón de *enviar*. Estoy usando **emailJS** y para las alertas **sweetalert2**. Gracias

```
const Contact = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm()

    e.target.reset()
  };

  const mostrarAlerta=()=>{

    swal.fire({
      title: "¡Listo!",
      text: "El mensaje ha sido enviado",
      icon: "success",
      confirmButtonText: "Aceptar"
    })
  }

  return (
    <section id='contact'>

      <div className='container contact__container'>
        <div className='contact__options'>
          <article className='contact__option'>
            <MdOutlineEmail className='contact__option-icon'/>
          </article>

          <article className='contact__option'>
            <BiPhoneCall className='contact__option-icon'/>
          </article>

          <article className='contact__option'>
            <BsWhatsapp className='contact__option-icon'/>
          </article>
        </div>

        <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail && mostrarAlerta()}>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Tu Nombre" required/>
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Tu Mail" required/>
          <textarea name="message" rows="7" placeholder='Tu Mensaje' required></textarea>
          <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Enviar Mensaje</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hola ! Podrías crear una validación que para que cuando los campos (almacenados en algún state) no tengan algún valor almacenado no deje ejecutarse la función que dispara el mensaje

Answer (score 0):

A mí me funcionó de esta manera

al pasar los datos a emailjs, produce una respuesta si fue efectivo el envío del email, y según la respuesta le envió el alert

```
function Contact() {

   
  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const alert = withReactContent(Swal);

    const target = e.target as typeof e.target

    emailjs.sendForm('service_id', 'template_id', target , '_id')
    .then(response => {  // aca capturo la respuesta con el .then y una validacion segun la respuesta
      console.log(response);
      if(response.status === 200){
        alert.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: <h2>Mesaje enviado con EXITO!!</h2>,
          html: <p>Respondere lo mas pronto posible</p>,
          timer: 7000,
        })
        
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))    
  }

  return (
    <section id='contact' className="py-10 px-3 text-white">
      <div className="text-center mt-8">
        <h3 className="text-4xl font-semibold">Contacta<span className="text-cyan-600">me</span></h3>
        <p className="text-gray-400 mt-3 text-lg">Ponerse en Contacto</p>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-16 flex md:flex-row flex-col gap-6 max-w-5xl bg-gray-800 p-6 rounded-lg mx-auto">
        <form onSubmit={sendEmail} className="flex flex-col flex-1 gap-6" action="">
          <input type="text" defaultValue="" name="user_name" placeholder="Tu Nombre" required />
          <input type="email" defaultValue="" name="user_email" placeholder="Tu Correo"  required/>
          <textarea placeholder="Tu Mensage" defaultValue="" name="message" rows={10} required></textarea>
          <button type="submit" className="btn-primary w-fit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
        </form>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-7">
          {
            contact?.map((contact, i: number) => (
              <div key={i} className="flex gap-4 w-full items-center">
                <div  className='min-w-[3.5rem] text-4xl min-h-[3.5rem] flex items-center justify-center text-white bg-cyan-600 rounded-full'>
                  <a href={contact.link} target='_blank'>
                    <IonIcon name={contact.icon}></IonIcon>
                  </a>                    
                </div>
                <p>{contact.text}</p>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ya realice la edición de la respuesta, espero se pueda entender